# Spring security filter executed when unneeded

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

When making a request to /api/v1/auth/authenticate with a valid body, my Postman gets a cookie named token with a jwt as a value. The token is set to expired in 20 minutes, when it is expired and I run the call with the exact body, and this time with a cookie, it gets rejected, saying basically that the cookie is expired, which is true. But, this endpoint does not need to be authenticated, as I have established in security config file. What is happening?

I want to also add that when changing the name of cookie in Postman, the request gets accepted and get my response along a new cookie named token, also when deleting the cookie, it gets accepted too.

AuthController:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/auth/")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AuthenticationController {

    private final AuthenticationService authenticationService;

    @PostMapping("/register")
    public ResponseEntity<AuthenticationResponse> register(@RequestPart("user") UserSignUpDto user,
                                                         @RequestPart("inpFile") MultipartFile profilePicture) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(authenticationService.register(user, profilePicture));
    }

    @PostMapping("/authenticate")
    public ResponseEntity<AuthenticationResponse> authenticate(@RequestBody UserLogInDto request,
                                                               HttpServletResponse response) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(authenticationService.authenticate(request, response));
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(ResponseStatusException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Exception> handleConflictError(ResponseStatusException exception) {
        // todo figure out ResponseStatusException
        return ResponseEntity.status(exception.getStatusCode()).body(exception);
    }

}
```

Security Config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter;
    private final AuthenticationProvider authProvider;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
                   auth.requestMatchers("/api/v1/auth/**").permitAll();
                   auth.requestMatchers("/home/**").permitAll();
                   auth.requestMatchers("/user/**").permitAll();
                   auth.requestMatchers("/picture/**").permitAll();
                   auth.anyRequest().authenticated();
                })
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authenticationProvider(authProvider)
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("http://localhost:4200"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(List.of("GET", "POST"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("Content-Type"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }

}
```

JwtAuthenticationFilter:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final JwtService jwtService;
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal( // todo: ask ChatGPT to explain this
                                     @NonNull HttpServletRequest request,
                                     @NonNull HttpServletResponse response,
                                     @NonNull FilterChain filterChain
    ) throws ServletException, IOException {
        final String userEmail;
        final String jwt;
        final Cookie jwtCookie = request.getCookies() != null ?  Arrays.stream(request.getCookies()).filter(cookie -> cookie.getName().equals("token"))
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(null):  null;

        if (jwtCookie == null) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }

        jwt = jwtCookie.getValue();
        userEmail = jwtService.extractUsername(jwt);// todo extract the userEmail token;
        if (userEmail != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(userEmail);

            if (jwtService.isTokenValid(jwt, userDetails)) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails,
                        null,
                        userDetails.getAuthorities()
                );

                authToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));

                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);
            }
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems this part from your `JwtAuthenticationFilter` code is relevant:

```
        final Cookie jwtCookie = request.getCookies() != null ?  Arrays.stream(request.getCookies()).filter(cookie -> cookie.getName().equals("token"))
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(null):  null;

        if (jwtCookie == null) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }
```

Note that if your cookie is not present with that exact name, your mechanism is skipped. Examining your `SecurityConfiguration` the filter is present in all requests so you need to either implement a mechanism to not add the filter to these unsecured endpoints or to add a method override to your filter so it does not activate on your unsecured endpoints:

```
@Override
protected boolean shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request) {
    // your implementation
}
```

One way would be using `request.getRequestURI()`.